# Passing an array to a JSON object for Jade rendering

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a node.js server written in express and at a certain moment I send to some .jade page an array. The problem is that when rendering the Jade page, the Jade compiler renders the array as `[object Object]` and the JavaScript compiler on Chrome complains about it saying "Unexpected identifier".

This is the Jade code:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
    head
    title= "Rankings"

    body
        h1 Ranking

        div(id="rankings")

    script(type='text/javascript')

        function fillRanking(){
            var rankArray = #{ranking};
            alert("inside fillranking");
            var divElement = document.getElementById("rankings");
            for(var i = 0; i< rankArray.length; i++){
                divElements.innerHTML += "" + i+1 + ". " + rankArray[i].Username + " " + rankArray[i].Points;
            }
        }

        fillRanking();
```

As you can see it's really simple, I just fill a div with the info given by what's inside the `#{ranking}` variable passed by node.js to Jade. The alert on the second line doesn't fire because the Unexpected Identifier error happens as soon as I try to assign the `#{ranking}` variable.

The following is the code in my node.js with express

```
app.get('/ranking', function (req, res) {
    //get the first ten people in the ranking
    var firstTen = getRanking(10, function(results){
        //compute the array of results
        var result = {
            ranking: [],
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            result.ranking[i] = results[i];
        }
        //render the ranking with all the info
        console.log(result);
        res.render(__dirname + '/pages/ranking/ranking.jade', {
            ranking: result,
        });
    });
});
```

I create an object with inside an array of results, I put the results I found out of the query inside it and I pass it to the rendering engine. The `console.log(results)` call prints the `result` object correctly, for example like this:

```
{ ranking: 
   [ { Username: 'usr1',
       _id: 4ed27319c1d767f70e000002,
       Points: 100 },
     { Username: 'usr2',
       _id: 4ed27326c1d767f70e000003,
       Points: 100 } ] 
}
```

I don't really know how to handle the variable passed to the Jade page. Whichever thing I do I keep getting the "Unexpected identifier" error.
Does anyone of you know how do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you don't have jade iterate over the array and build the list as part of the template? Search "Iteration" at https://github.com/visionmedia/jade.

Comment: Well, it's another way of seeing things. I got what you mean, but can you please provide an example of what you said as a response to this question? I would like to see how would you do it without incurring into the "Unexpected identifier" error. Thanks

Comment: Could try `{ranking: JSON.stringify(result)}`. To be clear, this is not optimal. Building the list as part of template with using Jade's 'Iteration' functionality completely avoids the need for the browser to execute JavaScript for this.

Comment: Doing this `var rankArray = JSON.stringify(#{ranking});` gives again Unexpected identifier error. Same happens with `var rankArray = {ranking: JSON.stringify(#{ranking})};`. I still don't see how building the list directly in HTML would avoid the JavaScript error I get, since every time JS tries to evaluate `#{ranking}` it fires the error.

Comment: My above suggestion should be placed in the route, not the template.

Comment: Ah ok sorry not for understanding that. Stringifying the result end up having something like this: ` var rankArray = {&quot;ranking&quot;:[{&quot;Username&quot;:&quot;...}]};` any ideas how to get rid of the &quot things?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5402/discussion-between-masiar-and-ryan-olds)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at the comments above and investigating a little bit more, here's what I've found to work:

Use this on your javascript (/controller):

```
...
res.render(__dirname + '/pages/ranking/ranking.jade', {
    ranking: JSON.stringify(ranking),
})
...
```

And on jade template:

```
...
function fillRanking(){
  var rankArray = !{ranking};
  alert("inside fillranking");
...
```

This works because !{} doesn't perform escaping.

Comment: Before you do this, make sure that ranking doesn't contain any unescaped user-controllable strings: http://escape.alf.nu/2/

Comment: really helped...thanks a lot man. your ans saved my 1 day work

Answer (score 10):

This works for me.

`JSON.stringify` the array (or any arbitrary JSON object really) on the server and then `JSON.parse` it on the client.

server-side:

```
res.render(__dirname + '/pages/ranking/ranking.jade', {
    ranking: JSON.stringify(result),
});
```

client-side:

```
var rankArray = JSON.parse( !{JSON.stringify(ranking)} );
```

Answer (score 3):

Because I also use the array from the controller for iteration, I did this:

```
res.render('template', pArrayOfData);
```

And in the jade code:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
            var _histData = !{JSON.stringify(pArrayOfData)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able make it work with a slight variation (thanks to the solutions above).

**From my code:**
Backend:

> Stringify the JSON array

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(apiData);  // <====
    res.render('gallery', { data: apiData });
});
```

Frontend:

> Stringify again with the !{}

```
    function injectDataOnView() {

        var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)}; // <====
        var divElement = document.getElementById('data');
        divElement.innerHTML = data[1]['id']; // <=== just a test, so no for loop
    }

    injectDataOnView();
```