# Node.js / Express - How to access 'req' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have a page which is loaded called `tournament/:key`, which is passing to it a `Tournament` object. As you can see from below the Jade template is accessing each variable from the `Tournament` by using, for example, `#{tournemantData.name}` which would print the `Tournament`'s `name` to the page. The set of `matches` is actually stored as an array within `Tournament`, and I would like to access these through a JavaScript file in order to work with them on this page, as eventually I would like a set of graphical brackets to be produced.

How would I access this `tournamentData` inside a JavaScript file?

```
  app.get('/tournament/:key', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    Tournament.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, tournamentData){
      if(!err && tournamentData){
        tournamentData = tournamentData;
        //util.log(tournamentData.teams[0]);
        res.render('tournamentDetails', { 'tournamentData' : tournamentData, seedsSerialized : JSON.stringify(tournamentData.teams) } );
      } else {
        util.log('Error in fetching Tournament by key : ' + req.params.key);
        res.json({
          'retStatus' : 'failure',
          'msg' : 'Error in fetching Tournament by key ' + req.params.key
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Jade:

```
        p Name: #{tournamentData.name}
        p ID: #{tournamentData._id}
        p Key: #{tournamentData.key}
        p Teams: #{tournamentData.teams}
        p Matches: #{tournamentData.matches}
        p Brackets:
        div.bracket
            #tournamentBrackets
            script(type='text/javascript')
                var seeds = var rankArray = !{seedsSerialized};
```

brackets.js

```
numRounds = Math.log(seeds.length) / Math.log(2);

/**
 * Randomize array element order in-place.
 * Using Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.
 */
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
};

shuffleArray(seeds);

var bracketData = {
    teams : [              // Matchups
        [ seeds[0].name,  seeds[1].name ],
    [ seeds[2].name,  seeds[3].name ]
  ],
  results : [[
      [ [1, 0], [1, 0] ],
      [ [1, 0], [1, 0] ]
    ]]
}

$(function() {
    $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
        init: bracketData
    });
});
```

EDIT: I have added the JavaScript file, what this is doing is using jQuery.bracket (a jQuery project I am using for generating nice looking brackets), at the moment you can see that I have manually put in the names of the teams.

The array of brackets inside `brackets.js` is the same format as in `tournamentData.matches`, but the basic idea is that I want to access this information from within this JavaScript file so that I can print the brackets with these teams.

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // tournament  is now the same as tournmentData in your express route
  var tournamentText = $(#tournamentData).text();
  var tournament = JSON.parse(tournamentText);
  console.log(tournament, tournament);

  $(function() {
    $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
      init: bracketData
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean : "I would like to access these through a JavaScript file"

Comment: publish your Tournement data using a route or as a static JSON file on your Express server and then make a $.get() or $.ajax request to retrieve it in your brackets.js file. If you need an explanation, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Lewis An answer would help, I think I understand what you are saying but I'm not sure how to code this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Answered and added some edits! Hope I understood you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can already access the variable in your Jade template meaning that you can access it in that page through Javascript.

Basically you already have the access to tournamentData object.

What you can do is get that tournamentData object and make it global JS variable or keep it in page scope.

Something like this in your template

```
- var matches = tournamentData.matches ;  //Specific scope
```

Or

```
- window.matches = tournamentData.matches; //Binded to window object global
```

Comment: I have updated my post to show the JS file if you could take a look, still stuck on this problem, I'm not trying to access it through Jade but through a seperate JS file. Any ideas?

Comment: When trying to do this I get, `window is not defined`?

Comment: You have to access to windows after your dom is ready and page is fully loaded.

Comment: Not sure I follow, I've added in something like Noah said below, adding in the Jade code and the window code once the document is ready, not sure how to get rid of the error from what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

You could publish your data on your Express server via a route like you've already shown with `/tournament/:key`.

Something like :

```
 app.get('/tournament-seeds/:key', function(req, res) {
    Tournament.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, tournamentData){
      res.json({ tournamentData: tournamentData });
    });
  });
```

Then ...

In your brackets.js file you want to make a call to fetch your seeds (?) data:

So changing your last function in brackets.js in your existing code to something like this (cut for brevity) should do what you want:

```
$(function() {   $.get('/tournament-seeds/somerandomkey', function(tournamentData){
   seeds = tournamentData.seeds;

    $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
        init: bracketData
    });   
  }); 
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm not suggesting this is the best way to do it, it's the quickest I can think of at the moment!

Alternatively you could blat the json into a variable directly in your template. See:
[Passing an array to a JSON object for Jade rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293363/passing-an-array-to-a-json-object-for-jade-rendering)

- EDIT *
  like :

On your route:

```
app.get('/tournament/:key', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    Tournament.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, tournamentData){
      tournamentData = tournamentData;
      util.log(tournamentData.teams[0]);
      res.render('tournamentDetails', { 'tournamentData' : tournamentData, seedsSerialized : JSON.stringify(tournamentData.seeds) } );
    });
  });
```

In your jade template:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
 var seeds = !{JSON.stringify(tournamentData.teams)};
```

In your brakets.js REMOVE your var seeds line.

Not tested but it should get you going.

Comment: Not sure I follow, the `/tournament/:key` is okay to use as it is at the moment? `tournamentData.teams` has an array of teams in it which is what I want to put into this `seeds` variable if that helps.

Comment: Waht do you mean by `$.get(''/tournament-seeds/somerandomkey',`? This is another route? `tournamentData` holds all the information about a tournament when it is passed to the Jade view as you can see from the output of the name etc of the tournament. Can you not access `tournamentData` from within the JS file?

Comment: @germainelol ^^ yeah. You can't access the tournament data directly from the js file as this is run on the client and your Jade is being "rendered" on the server. See my last comment re dropping the code into the template.

Comment: Sorry is there any way you could move this to chat to explain this? I thought I was doing this by passing it to the Jade template, but it seems not. I like the idea of passing it directly to the template as it's only going to be small amounts of data but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Take a look at : See: Passing an array to a JSON object for Jade rendering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293363/passing-an-array-to-a-json-object-for-jade-rendering

Comment: Reading that, the only difference I see is that I would pass to the template for example `JSON.stringify(tournamentData.teams)`, but I'm not sure how this allows me to access it from within the JS file.

Comment: It's the second bit that's important: ...
function fillRanking(){
  var rankArray = !{ranking};
  alert("inside fillranking");
...

That's directly added to your template - so it's javascript written in your template but executed in the browser

Comment: So I should be putting all of the `brackets.js` code into the browser effectively? And to access it, pass the data to the Jade page as a JSON string as well so that the JS can access it on the page.

Comment: No. as long as the brackets.js is called from the resource that is rendered from your route you'll just need to be abel to reference the JSON, a global variable will do what you need.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow I'm afraid, I appreciate the help but I don't follow.

Comment: No worries - I've tried to write it for you above- but can't guarantee it's all correct. Have a play!

Comment: Well the brackets now appear which is a positive thing, playing around with it I noticed it should have been `{tournamentData.teams}` but changed that. I can't seem to get the team names to output to the brackets though, it must be working with the JSON you created as the brackets have the correct number of rounds which is calculated using `seeds` as you can see. Any idea? The brackets are currently blank, will update the OP with the updated code in one second

Comment: I suspect that it might have something to do with the team names not being quoted - view your source in the browser and see. If they aren't then you'll need to quote them (somehow)

Comment: How/where do you mean sorry?

Comment: In your HTML (what the view renders). In your browser, right click and view source. the json team names should be quoted. like "team name" rather than just: team name

Comment: If I inspect the brackets code, the team name is not actually anywhere in the brackets. The name of the tournament for example is rendered as `<p>Name: My Tournament</p>`, and if I manually enter a name of the team in the JS file, the team name is rendered as: `<b>Team 1</b>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27958/discussion-between-lewis-and-germainelol)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "JavaScript file" I am assuming you mean a client-side javascript file and not a server-side file in Express.

1. The first way is to construct the client-side javascript file dynamically on each request and add in the tournament data directly into the script.
2. The second option is to include to the tournament _id on the page and then have your client-side javascript perform an ajax request to the server to get the rest of the tournament data as json
3. The third is to embed all the data about your tournament directly into the html and then extract it in your client side script

Embedding your tournament data as a JSON string in the templtae

### Jade template

```
div(style="visibility: hidden")#tournamentData
  !{JSON.stringify(tournamentData)}
```

### Client Side Javascript

Now in your in your client-side javascript you can access the text inside the #tournamentData div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // tournament  is now the same as tournmentData in your express route
   var tournamentText = $(#tournamentData).text()
   var tournament = JSON.parse(tournamentText)
   console.log(tournament, tournament)
   $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
     init: bracketData
   })
})
```

Comment: I have updated my post to show the JS file if you could take a look that would be great as I am still rather stuck.

Comment: When adding `-window.tournament = tournamentData` to the Jade template, I get the error `window is not defined` appear when loading the page?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot that window was not available, see my edits of embedding the JSON tournament data in a hidden div on the page

Comment: This printed the entire tournament to the page for some reason, I think it's because the div is not actually being hidden.

Comment: div(style="visibility: hidden")#tournamentData

Comment: Thanks, successfully got that working. I'm pretty confused though, adding the code you suggested for the JavaScript actually stops the brackets from being displayed which is odd. I have tried adding the `document.ready` function in, tried adding that code into the function at the bottom of the brackets.js file, and tried adding it outside of both functions, but the brackets are always not being displayed.

Comment: do you still have $(function() { ..}) in addition to the $(document).ready(function() { ..}? If so you should move the body of the first $(function... into the document ready body

Comment: Please see the update to the post, this is what I've tried, but I can't get the brackets to appear any more, and don't know how to check if the code you suggested is working. The other code seems to be breaking it, but I don't really know how to inspect why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27950/discussion-between-noah-and-germainelol)