# How to do server-side rendering in Jade with an Array of json objects instead of a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, pug

On my Node.js sever, I have an array of JavaScript objects that were given to me by a MySQL query. I need to send that Array to my Jade template, so I do this in my router.js:

```
data = JSON.stringify(rows[0]);
res.render('yourUploads', {fromServer:data});
```

console.log(data) reads something like this: [{key:val},{key:val},{key:val}]

Now I'm trying to iterate over this object in Jade like so:

```
- for (object in JSON.parse(fromServer)) {
        +posMixin(object.toString())
- }
```

object.toString() just gives me "0", "1", "2" object.val seems to be null.

I thought this was a duplicate of [how to render json object in jade and loop through results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301258/how-to-render-json-object-in-jade-and-loop-through-results), but I'm dealing with this Array of json instead of json. This is a lot like [Passing an array to a JSON object for Jade rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293363/passing-an-array-to-a-json-object-for-jade-rendering), but I'm trying to use a mixin and run sever-side rendering, not move it in to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

For in loop work a bit different. It passes the key ( of your array), so you might need to loop over the array, and then over each key :

```
var arr=JSON.parse(fromServer);
arr.forEach(function(obj){
  for(key in object){
    console.log(key+":"+object[key]);
  }
 });
```